# Get key with minimum value from python dictionary for Dijkstra Algorithm implementation

Tags: python, dictionary, dijkstra

For implementing  Dijkstra Algorithm I have two dictionaries like

```
visited={k:0 for k, v in graph.items()}
cost={k:10000000 for k, v in graph.items()}
```

visited is 0 if completed

sample contents of cost and visited are

```
{'a': 0, 'b': 3, 'c': 5, 'd': 2, 'e': 14, 'f': 10, 'g': 7, 'h': 10000000, 'i': 10000000, 'k': 10000000, 'j': 10000000}
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 0, 'h': 0, 'i': 0, 'k': 0, 'j': 0}
```

to select the next node with minimum cost value I am using

```
min(dict((k,cost[k]) for k in [i for i,x in visited.items() if x==0]).items(), key=lambda y: y[1])
```

Is there any better way of doing this? Will this scale with an increase in the number of nodes?

Comment: A standard implementation of Djikstras is to use a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) for getting the minimum cost edge. See: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-in-java-using-priorityqueue/

Comment: sorry, the constrain was only to list and dict. no packages.

Comment: Roll your own implementation of priority queue then.